# Get data from previous month in Doctrine2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I need to all data from the table that were created in last month. I've create below code but it gives below error in DQL, however the SQL query is correct when run it.

Error :

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 138: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got '-'
```

Code is;

```
$compCases = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('EFuturesCrmBundle:CasesCompensation')
            ->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->select('c.id')
            ->where('c.caseStatus =:status')
            ->andWhere('YEAR(c.caseStatusDate) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)')
            ->andWhere('MONTH(c.caseStatusDate) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)')
            ->setParameter('status', 'resolve')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

DQL is not support to the `INTERVAL`  so how this possible in Doctrine2 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use this kind of approach:

```
 $now = new \DateTime('now');
 $delay = new \Datetime('last month');

 $compCases = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('EFuturesCrmBundle:CasesCompensation')
        ->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->select('c.id')
        ->where('c.caseStatus = :status')
        ->andWhere('c.caseStatusDate <= :now')
        ->andWhere('c.caseStatusDate >= :delay')
        ->setParameter('status', 'resolve')
        ->setParameter('now', $now)
        ->setParameter('delay', $delay)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

Hope it can help you.

Comment: This is solve the part of issue. however I want to get data from not today. It should be last month last date to last month first date.
How can I get  last month last date instead of  `$now = new \DateTime('now');` ?

Comment: Okay, like this for exemple: `$from = new \DateTime('first day of last month 00:00:00'); $to = new \DateTime('first day of this month 00:00:00');`